# What does this onsubmit code do?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

What does this code do?

```
onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular this question could benefit from a little more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoded, it is:

```
return window.Event && Event.__inlineSubmit && Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)
```

So, it tests whether `Event` and `Event.__inlineSubmit` exist, and if they do, it calls
`Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)`.

Answer (score 0):

It will return true if all those objects are defined, otherwise will return false.
It's a very ugly code. inline javascripts are a very bad practice.

Note: In my browser. Event._inlineSubmit doesn't exist. So I think it should return false.